# Jquery Datatable: apply search filter on server side data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Data is not filtered in server side mode. How can I filter?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>@_stringLocalizer["page.Name"]</th>
        <th>@_stringLocalizer["page.SurName"]</th>
        <th>@_stringLocalizer["page.Gender"]</th>
        <th>@_stringLocalizer["page.BloodGroup"]</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
            <td>The table body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>batuhan</td>
          <td>batuhan</td>
          <td>batuhan</td>
          <td>batuhan</td>
          <td>batuhan</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>

var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "bDestroy": true, 
                    serverSide: true,
                    processing:true,
                    searching: true,
                    ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {
            var out = [];
 
            for ( var i=data.start, ien=data.start+data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                out.push( [ i+'-1', i+'-2', i+'-3', i+'-4', i+'-5' ] );
            }
 
            setTimeout( function () {
                callback( {
                    draw: data.draw,
                    data: out,
                    recordsTotal: 5000000,
                    recordsFiltered: 5000000
                } );
            }, 50 );
        },  
                    // columns: [
                    //     { "data": "Id" },
                    //     { "data": "Ad" },
                    //     { "data": "Soyad" },
                    //     { "data": "Cinsiyet" },
                    //     { "data": "KanGrubu" }
                    // ],
                    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
                    buttons: [   {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: 'Hasta_Bilgileri'
                    },'copy' ],
                    rowId: 'id',
                    scrollY: '400px',
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                });
                 

$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

actually these are not my real codes. but in my real codes, the server side mode is turned on. and according to my research on the internet, there are problems with data filtering in serverside mode.

In my real code, I connect to the api with ajax and pull the data. but I wrote a very basic code to explain the question to you comfortably. Here, the serverside mode is on. and it doesn't filter the data. if i don't get the data with serverside mode it is filtering. So how to filter data in serverside mode? he needs to write the filter in the search input. For example, he should bring 'batuhan' ones.

Comment: The point of using `serverSide: true` is because you have too much data - and processing the entire data set in a browser is too slow. By using server-side processing you are telling DataTables that it does not need to perform sorting/filtering/paging in the browser. You will take care of all that in the server. So _your server_ has to provide all that logic - and it will deliver one page at a time (a _small, fast_ subset of the overall data) to the browser. See the [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) overview.

Comment: If you don't have "too much" data for the browser to handle, don't use server-side processing - just use Ajax on its own and let DataTables do all the sorting/filtering/paging for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call an endpoint where the server side processing will occur.

this is the tutorial I followed when I had to set it up
https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/

this is c# but modify to whatever server side language you are using.

here is the whole datatable implementation for a project I did.
https://github.com/bryandellinger/minerals/blob/main/minerals/src/accounting/managePayments/initDataTable.js

```
 processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      filter: true,
      ajax: {
        url: './api/RoyaltyPaymentDataTableApi',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data(data) {
          data.from = $('#from').val();
          data.to = $('#to').val();
          data.paymentTypeId = parseInt($('#paymentTypeDropDownId').val(), 10);
        },
      },
```

then in your endpoint retrieve the variables from the post and do your filtering

the example below is c# but modify to your language as needed.

here is the entire backend controller for the same project.
https://github.com/bryandellinger/minerals/blob/main/minerals/Controllers/RoyaltyPaymentDataTableApiController.cs

```
 var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
                var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
                var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
                var paymentTypeId = Request.Form["paymentTypeId"].FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
                var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                int recordsTotal = 0;
                string to = Request.Form["to"].FirstOrDefault();
                string from = Request.Form["from"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thank you. so how should i make tbody in my html table? I couldn't find it in your github project. I did the api part and the datatable part as you said. So how should I do the table part in html?

Comment: If I am sending 10 data from the api it reflects the data count correctly in the table. but it cannot show the content of the data. why could it be?

Comment: no tbody needed the config of datatables will handle it.   here is the one I am referencing is set up   https://github.com/bryandellinger/minerals/blob/main/minerals/src/views/accounting/managePayments/index.handlebars

Comment: thanks. but still it didn't. It produces as many rows as the number of data returned from the api. but it doesn't show the content of the data. It says columns could not be matched. I connected with fetch api. It returns as many data as the number of data, but they are empty. If I convert json with newton json, this time the data comes in fetch. but still can't show it with ajax. It finds the column but can't seem to render it. Maybe it's the data content. I did not understand.

Comment: I'm not just pulling data from the database. Since it is a trial, I add 10 numbers to the list with the for loop in the api part. I am sending the list.